# Can I drive alone to the UK driving test with a valid international driving license?

Tags: united-kingdom, driving-license

My US license cannot be changed to the UK's, so I am in the process of obtaining the UK driver's license. I have the learner license and have passed the theory test.

I have a valid US driver's license with an international driving license and I have been in the UK for 10 months.

Non-international license holders must be accompanied by a driving instructor or an adult with the driving license to go to the UK driving test location to take the driving test.

Do international drivers who are still allowed to drive in the UK legally with the home country's driving license have to bring someone else to the UK driving test too?

**Can I just drive to the test center with a rental car alone?**. If I don't pass, can I still drive back with my home country's driving license?

Thank you for your help in sharing the information.

Comment: I would recommend you check with the car rental company. They may have T&C relating to this scenario

Comment: Thank you @Traveller. I googled and found out I need to rent a car from companies that specialise in driving test car rentals.

Comment: Were you able to drive to the test centre alone and take the test?